# Api Controller: Json decapitalizes the names of properties

Tags: json, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an api controller in my webcore application:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        protected ApplicationDbContext dbContext;
        public DataController(ApplicationDbContext dc)
        {
            dbContext = dc;
        }

        [HttpGet("Categories")]
        public List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            var l = dbContext.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
            return l;
        }
    }
```

And the class:

```
public class Category
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

When I Invoke the controller action to get the categories, in the response the name of properties are all decapitalized. That is:
Id becomes id,
Name becomes name,
Description becomes description.

**Edit:
I have tried also:

```
 [HttpGet("Test")]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            var l = dbContext.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
            return Json(l);
        }
```

And still the properties are all decapitalized

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Make sure camelcasing is not enabled for JSON. Please check this [link](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/25/asp-net-webapi-tip-3-camelcasing-json.aspx)

Comment: Is camelcasing enabled by default in json? I am not setting it anyway in my code

Comment: My question is I do not want json decapitalize the property names, but leave it as they are. That should be default behavior.

Comment: the API from where you get a response is in your control or not? @user1238784

Comment: @D-john yes it is

Comment: so properties names of that class are capital?? can you please provide? @user1238784

Comment: @D.john yes they are capital. I have already  posted the class as well.

Comment: @user1238784 use Newtonsoft Please find my whole example with screenshot let me know if you get some issues

Comment: @D-John Your example works but I need something that works with my example.  See my further try, using json. IT still gives decapitalized properties

Comment: @user1238784 please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>  
/// Welcome Note Message  
/// </summary>  
/// <returns>In a Json Format</returns>  
public JsonResult WelcomeNote()
{
    Category cs = new Category();
    cs.Id = 123456;
    cs.Name = "ExampleName";
    cs.Description = "Abcd";

    return Json(cs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This, I am getting from above code which you want I guess 
[image]

> [Refer this for more good Examples](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2ed7ae/jsonresult-type-in-mvc/?)

Comment: If I follow your example the property names are Capitalized, but I need something that works with my example. What you did is to serialize the data in the controller and give the serialized string as output.

Comment: u said that my class property is also capitalized right? @user1238784

Comment: @d.john, your property names are capitalized which is good, but I need something working with my examples. I do not want to return a string, I want to return a Json

Comment: you are calling returning JSON which internally doing this so why we don't make code which will do this stuff @user1238784

Comment: Your updated example still does not work for me, the name of properties are decapitalized. I do not understand why.

Comment: Please check your Class model I have Also Attach image also @user1238784  now other properties are capital  right other than name?